# How to do Stress Testing of transaction modules/payment modules

Tags: load, performance-testing, load-testing

I am working on an Android App which deals with "Secured Payment" Using Debit/Credit Cards.How I could test the stress/capacity of the "Payment Process" where custom session Id is required for secure login, Card Info is required for Transaction ...

My Summarized query: How Companies like Payoneer do Stress Testing of their transaction modules? Which frameworks/tools/scripts they generally use?

Comment: STEPS:
  1. Logging in(get individual session data)
  2. Navigating to Card Payment
  3. Inputting data (Card Data)
  4. Submitting forms

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions in JMeter ,session data & another type of data can be handeled easily.So Proper use of [Regular Expressions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=BM_Blog&utm_campaign=advanced-load-testing-jmeter-1-correlations) will help to do Stress Testing of transaction modules/payment modules using apache jmeter.